# How is a trapdoor used in cryptography?

Tags: trapdoor

Given a trapdoor function, is there a way to explain in all generality how it will be used in a cryptographic system in a simple way?
I am writing a project for high school and I am looking for a way to explain why trapdoor functions are so useful.

Comment: Your question is very broad. There are ways to do _things_ in cryptography using trapdoors, but it's not unlike asking "how are functions used in mathematics".

Comment: Trying to clarify this towards something less broad — What research have you done? What did you find? And why didn't your findings answer your question? After all, it's not as if there aren't ample explanations out there in form of online articles, PDF papers, and even printed books. Understanding your knowledge level on the subject might help answerers to provide an oin-point, helpful answer to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct use of a trapdoor one-way function is to create asymmetric cryptosystems such as Public Key Encryption (PKE), Key Encapsulation Mechanisms (KEM), and Digital Signatures.

### An analogy

A trapdoor one-way function is like a lock box that is supplied to the user in an opened configuration. Any user may place an item inside the box, then close the lid, which latches the lock closed as it does so. Only the person who has the key can then open the box to obtain the item inside.

In this analogy, the lock box itself is the public key, and the key that opens the box is the private key.

- It might be more accurate to say that the public key is some kind of lock box manufacturing device, but the analogy only needs to be so accurate.
- Also, for the sake of simplicity we will assume that the box can only be opened with the appropriate key.

### Public Key Encryption

Public Key Encryption enables anyone to encrypt a message which is may only be decrypted by a single target recipient. This can be accomplished by a trapdoor function.

Using the lock box analogy to perform public key encryption is simple: Simply place your message into the lock box, close the lid, and send the result to the key holder. They are the only ones that can open the box and retrieve the message.

### Key Encapsulation Mechanism

The downside of the PKE technique is that if you want to send a large message, you probably won't have room in the box. The solution is to use the box as a key encapsulation mechanism instead.

To use the trapdoor lock box as a KEM, you instead write down a relatively small, random message and insert that into the box. Then you use that random message as a cryptographic key for a symmetric cipher and use that to encrypt your actual larger message.

- This also has the advantage of being more time/space efficient, as the symmetric cipher takes much less time/space to compute/store than the trapdoor does.

### Digital Signature

One more use for a trapdoor function is to create a Digital Signature. The lock box analogy slightly breaks down here, but hopefully you already have a handle on the asymmetric nature of what a trapdoor function provides.

Given the private key and an arbitrary output of a trapdoor function, you can* invert the output to find the corresponding input that produced it. Without the private key this is assumed to be intractable for anyone else to do.

Given a public key, a random output, and the corresponding input, we can use the public key and input to generate the output. Since it would be too hard for anyone else other than the private key holder to have produced the input, we can assume that they were the one that produced the input. This enables us to verify the possession of the private key without having access to the private key, which forms the basis for a digital signature scheme. We can submit arbitrary random outputs to the entity believed to hold the private key, and if they can return the corresponding input, we know that we are communicating with them.

### Disclaimer

This is a very simplified explanation which intentionally ignores many details - I am assuming that the asker knows nothing/very little and is not looking for a rigorously correct explanation.

*This doesn't necessarily work for all trapdoors, but this is a generalized explanation anyways, so we won't worry about that.

Comment: I'd say "The downside of the PKE technique is" that it's completely insecure. First of all it's deterministic. Second of all you said "trapdoor one-way function", not permutation. A one-way function does not necessarily hide all our even most of the preimage.

Comment: @Maeher I'd say that the box would be semi-transparent and that you'd need additional measures to mask the message inside the box. The box might be too small for the message as well. But maybe that would be over-extending the analogy...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's the problem with analogies, they are usually wrong and lead to people getting the wrong idea.

Answer (score 2):

All generality, no—that's pretty much guaranteed to be too broad of a question here.

Here's a specific example.  Let $S$ be a finite set $F$ a public trapdoor permutation of $S$ with secret inverse $F^{-1}$, and $H\colon S \to \{0,1\}^{256}$ a uniform random function.  For a member of the public to send a message $m$ to the possessor of $F^{-1}$, they can:

1. Pick an element $s \in S$ uniformly at random.
2. Compute $\sigma = F(s)$.  $\sigma$ conceals the element $s$; only the possessor of $F^{-1}$ can compute it.
3. Compute $k = H(s)$.  $H$ destroys any structure of $S$ to give a uniform random bit string for symmetric-key cryptography.
4. Use $k$ as the secret key for authenticated encryption<sup>*</sup> of the message $m$ yielding ciphertext $c$.
5. Transmit $(\sigma, c)$.

The recipient, on receiving $(\sigma, c)$, recovers $s = F^{-1}(\sigma)$, computes $k = H(s)$, and decrypts/verifies $c$ with $k$.

This specific method of generating $\sigma$ and $k$, and deriving $k$ from $\sigma$ using secret knowledge of $F^{-1}$, is usually known as [RSA-KEM, for RSA key encapsulation mechanism](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf), because the only trapdoor permutations anyone cares about arise from the RSA trapdoor permutation family.<sup>†</sup>  In this case, $S = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for a large composite $n$ with large prime factors, and $F(s) = s^e \bmod n$ where $e \geq 3$ is coprime with $\lambda(n)$ so that $e$ has an inverse $d$ modulo $\lambda(n)$ such that $F^{-1}(\sigma) = \sigma^d \bmod n$.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> For example, they might use the authenticated encryption scheme AES-GCM or NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305.  The security property really required here, [*DEM*, or data encapsulation mechanism](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf), is actually more modest than authenticated encryption—more like one-time authenticated encryption.</sub>

<sub><sup>†</sup> Rabin/Blum-type permutations of quadratic residues by squaring require a little more effort to sort out, and, in spite of their high performance and neat simplicity and reduction to factoring, nobody actually uses them in practice.</sub>

Comment: Thank you ! This answer helped clarify the research that I've been doing.